# C++ Linker issues, is there a generalized way to troubleshoot these?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I know next to nothing about the linking process, and it almost always gets in the way when I am trying to start a new project or add a new library.  Whenever I search for fixes to these type of errors, I will find people with a similar problem but rarely any sort of fix.

Is there any generalized way of going about finding what the problem is, and fixing it?

I'm using visual studio 2010, and am statically linking my libraries into my program.  My problems always seem to stem from conflicts with LIBCMT(D).lib, MSVCRT(D).lib, and a few other libraries doublely defining certain functions.  If it matters at all, my intent is to avoid using "managed" C++.

Comment: Knowing next to nothing about something, and asking for a generalized way to troubleshoot... It seems obvious that the best medicine is prevention here. Learn how it works so you can use best practices, prevent errors, and troubleshoot them.

Comment: okay, just read a primer on it.  There's a lot of hateful things I want to say about it.  Like how linkers should not exist in this day and age.  But I will stuff it I guess.  I at least understand the concept and what they're supposed to do now, though.

Comment: [Quick introduction on linkers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/12/9905953.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your error is related to LIBCMT(D).lib and the like, usually that depends from the fact that you are linking against a library that uses a different CRT version than yours. The only real fix is to either use the library compiled for the same version of the CRT you use (often there is the "debug" and "release" version also for this reason), either (if you are desperate) change the CRT version you use to match the one of the library.

What is happening behind the scenes is that both your program and your library need the CRT functions to work correctly, and each one already links against it. If they are linking against the same version of it nothing bad happens (the linker sees that it's the same and doesn't complain), otherwise there are multiple conflicting implementations of the same functions, so the linker doesn't know which are right for which object modules (and also, since they are probably not binary compatible, internal data structures of the two CRTs will be incompatible).

Comment: That is exactly what it was.  I had set one of my libraries to statically link against the STD library, instead of using the shared library.  Hence all the multiple defined stuff from libcmt.  Thanks!

Comment: @Clairvoire: that's a common problem with static libraries. That's why when you have to install e.g. Boost you have to generate the static libraries for every CRT available (and with VC++ 2003 there were all the Debug/Release combinations for single threaded static, multithreaded static, multithreaded dll), which is quite inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

The specific link errors you mentioned (with LIBCMT(D).lib, MSVCRT(D).lib libraries) are related to conflicts in code generation options between modules/libraries in your program.

When you compile a module, the compiler automatically inserts in the resulting .obj some references to the runtime libraries (LIBCMT&MSVCRT). Now, there is one version of these libraries for each code generation mode (I'm referring to the option at Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library). So if you have two modules compiled with a different mode, each of them will reference a different version of the library, the linker will try to include both, and of course there'll be duplicated symbols, since essentially all the symbols are the same in these libraries, only their implementations differ.

The solution comes in three parts. First, make sure all the modules in a project use the same mode. Second, if you have dependencies between projects, all of them have to use the same mode. Third, if you use third-party libraries, you have to either know which mode they use (and adopt it) or be able to recompile them with the desired mode.

The last one is the most difficult. Sometimes, libraries come pre-compiled, and not always the provider gives information about the mode used. Worse, if you're using more than one third-party library, they may have conflicting modes. In those cases, you have no better option than trial-and-error.

Also notice that each Visual Studio version has its own set of runtime libraries, so when using third-party libraries you have to use those compiled with the same version of Visual Studio you're using. If the provider doesn't offer it, your only choice is to recompile yourself.